# siunitx - distinguish unit with prefix and without

Tags: siunitx

I would like to distinguish two cases when using the unit `\byte`:

1. if used *without* prefix it should be written as "Byte" in the text
2. if used *with* prefix, e.g. `\kilo\byte`, I would like to get "kB"

Do I need to declare different units for use with/without prefix or can this
be handled by the package?

Comment: Just a friendly reminder, we usually don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.  (See [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) for more awesome info.)

Comment: If it's not mentioned in the manual (I haven't read it), then it isn't so provided.  The best way to find out is to [skim through it](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) (Ctrl/Cmd+F is your friend ;)).  I don't *think* it is, but this behaviour can probably be tacked on.

Comment: Units are symbols, not abbreviations. If you don't want the symbol, spell out the name: “10~bytes”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[binary-units]{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\mybyte{Byte}

\begin{document}

One thousand bytes is \SI{1}{\kibi\byte}

One byte is \SI{1}{\mybyte}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Suggestion:

- Use `byte` instead of `Byte` when the unit is not abbreviated.

Answer (score 1):

The second case you mention:

> if used with prefix, e.g. \kilo\byte, I would like to get "kB"

Is the default behavior with `siunitx`, so you shouldn't worry about it.  E.g.

```
\SI{1}{\kilo\byte}
```

For the first one:

> if used without prefix it should be written as "Byte" in the text

I would suggest you define your own macro named `\mybyte` at your preamble.  E.g.

```
\newcommand{mybyte}{Byte}
```

So when you want to have the prefix, just type:

```
One thousand bytes is \SI{1}{\kilo\byte}
```

or alternatively:

```
 One byte is \SI{1}{\mybyte}
```

Code example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\mybyte}{Byte}

\begin{document}

One thousand bytes is \SI{1}{\kilo\byte}

One byte is \SI{1}{\mybyte}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to define `\mybyte` as a proper unit using `\declareSIUnit`, instead of using `\newcommand`?

Comment: @Jake Could be, but I don't know if when using `\SI{1}{\kilo\byte}` would work

Comment: Since `Byte` is not an abbreviation, the space between `1` and `Byte` should be a normal text space, not a thin space.